# Multiply field in array of object by Mongo aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given the following record:

```
{
  "_id": "5ebe47995dc5b683d050c396",
  "date": "2020-05-05 00:00:00",
  "insertTime": "2020-05-15 15:41:13.039000",
  "resultSummary": {
    "total": [
      {
        "date": "2019-09-12 00:00:00",
        "actualCost": 123,
      },
      {
        "date": "2019-09-13 00:00:00",
        "actualCost": 456,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to multiply `actualCost` by 100 using Mongo aggregation.

Expected outcome:

```
{
  "_id": "5ebe47995dc5b683d050c396",
  "date": "2020-05-05 00:00:00",
  "insertTime": "2020-05-15 15:41:13.039000",
  "resultSummary": {
    "total": [
      {
        "date": "2019-09-12 00:00:00",
        "actualCost": 12300,
      },
      {
        "date": "2019-09-13 00:00:00",
        "actualCost": 45600,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I tried:

```
{'$set':
     {'resultSummary.total.actualCost': {'$multiply': ['$resultSummary.total.$.actualCost', 100]},
     }
}
```

However it seems Mongo cannot recognise $ and gives

```
Error: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `resultSummary.total` is an `array`, we cannot apply `$multiply` operator. Instead, use `$map` operator and apply multiplication individually.

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      resultSummary: {
        total: {
          $map: {
            input: "$resultSummary.total",
            as: "total",
            in: {
              "date": "$$total.date",
              "actualCost": {
                $multiply: [
                  "$$total.actualCost",
                  100
                ]
              }                  
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FbLF8u7-Vy5)